# Help with this grammar, XMl in Bison

Tags: xml, grammar, bison

i have the following grammar and i dont know how to fix it. I check that if it is ambiguos with the Wirth conditions but maybe this is irrelevant because bison use an LR parser:

**First Version, 7 shift/reduce**

```
S->DE
D->aKc
E-><J K E2
E2-> /> | > H I
I-> </J>
K-> | KL
L-> j ='N'
H-> | HT
T-> N E3
E3-> | E N
N -> | N N2
N2-> text | j
```

where j is a valid word, and text is just text without any special caracter, a and c are the string that surround an xml declaration.
one of the conflicts that appear is a shift/reduce that cause that the rule E3->/*empty*/  get useless.

I make some improvements with the epsilon transition

**Second Version 2shift/reduce**

```
S-> D E
D-> a D2
D2->|K c
E-> <J E1
E1-> E2 | K E2
E2-> /> | > HI
I-> </J>
K-> L | K L
L-> J= 'N'
N-> N N2 | N2
N2-> X | J
H-> HT | T
T-> N|E
```

the 2 shift reduce problem are that after read an X or J, and comes other X or J, it doesn't know if it reduce T or shift and prepare to use N->N N2 | N2

**Third Version 2shift/reduce, but recognize well my sample xml files**

```
S-> D E
D-> a D2
D2-> K c | c     // a is "<?xml version=\"1.0\"" and c is "?>"
E-> <J E1
E1-> E2 | K E2
E2-> /> | > E3   // this is the other correction, for the case of an empty element
E3-> HI | I
I-> </J>
K-> L | K L
L-> J= 'N'
N-> N N2 | N2
N2-> X | J    // X and J are word(any strange word) and ValidWord(used in element and atributes names)
H-> HT | T
T-> N|E
```

Answer (score 1):

That's about as cryptic as it can get and I imagine you're getting lots of conflicts.

The left-recursion in clause N -> | N N2 suggests an infinite loop where the 2nd N is continually reduced to empty using the 1st rule.

If E3->empty and N->empty then T->empty and if H->empty in its first clause, it follows that H->empty because HT->empty. And so on.

I'd start with something easier to get a better understanding of parser-writing.

Comment: thanks, yea i'm having serious troubles with this, i read the bison documentation and they recommend that if you must put a recursion it has to be in the left. i did some toys examples but what i need is this, a parser for xml...i'm getting in total 7 shift/reduces conflicts, my major limitation is how deal with epsilon transitions and not break the validity of the parser....i'm going to continue the reading, if a make any improvement i will inform you

Comment: i make some improvements, look the second version

Comment: Instead of letting us guess in the dark, it would help if you posted the SR/RR conflicts you are getting

Comment: i edited the question with the conflict explained at the end........remember X and J are terminals